# UICollectionViewCell Protocol is not working

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, swift-protocols

I have a Protocol inside my CellClass which is detect the function 'editCommentInFeed'. I have create an 'editButton' inside my Cell and define the handler with 'editCommentField' which is calling per Delegate the function and over give the 2 Parameters. This 2 Parameters are important I need this Informations from the cell to detect in future actions which will be provided.

For example I had tried to print something when the Button ist Pressed inside the Cell. But even this Statement is not execute.

```
//This is the Cell Class

protocol CommentFeedProtocol {
    func editCommentInFeed(cell: CommentCell, comment: Comment)
}

class CommentCell: BaseCell {

      var delegate: CommentFeedProtocol?

      let editButton: UIButton = {

        let editbttn = UIButton(type: UIButton.ButtonType.system)
        editbttn.setImage(UIImage(named: "editButton"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
        editbttn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editCommentField), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)

        return editbttn
    }()


    override func setUpCell() {
        super.setUpCell()

        backgroundColor = UIColor.white


        setUpCommentCell()

    }

    fileprivate func setUpCommentCell(){

        addSubview(profileImageView)
        addSubview(editButton)
        addSubview(commentTextView)
        addSubview(seperator)

        profileImageView.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 8, paddingLeft: 8, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 40, height: 40)
        profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 40/2

        editButton.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: nil, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 5, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 5, paddingRight: 10, width: 45, height: 0)

        commentTextView.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: profileImageView.rightAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: editButton.leftAnchor, paddingTop: 4, paddingLeft: 4, paddingBottom: 4, paddingRight: 4, width: 0, height: 0)

        seperator.anchor(top: bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 5, paddingLeft: 20, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 20, width: 0, height: 1.5)


    }


    /*Objecthandler*/

    @objc func editCommentField(){
        guard let comment = comment else { return}
        delegate?.editCommentInFeed(cell: self, comment: comment)
    }
```

```
// This is the CollectionViewController
// As you can see I am also add the Protocol to the class 

class CommentsController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, CommentFeedProtocol {

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.title = "Kommentare"

        postButton.imageView?.alpha = 0.5
        postButton.isEnabled = false


        collectionView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
        collectionView.register(CommentCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: commentCell)
        collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true

        self.collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        fetchComments()

    }


override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: commentCell, for: indexPath) as! CommentCell


        cell.comment = comments[indexPath.item]
        cell.delegate = self

        return cell
    }

// Here is the Delegate Function

    func editCommentInFeed(cell: CommentCell, comment: Comment) {
        print("Button was Pressed")
    }
```

You can see inside the example that I am Adding the Protocol to the class and also call the function inside the Class. I am not getting a Error Message. The Button is only light hovered when is clicked, but don't execute anything ?!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UICollectionViewCell Protocol is not working correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56221525/uicollectionviewcell-protocol-is-not-working-correct)

Answer (score 0):

Seems the delegate is not set to your ViewController.
inside your `cellForItemAt` function, you need to set `cell.delegate = self`.
so when your cell calls `delegate.editCommentInFeed` it actually calls your viewController's `editCommentInFeed` implemented function.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer! I am sorry about the little copy mistake above. ```cell.delegate = self``` is already inside my ```cellForItemAt``` the problem is it is still not working so I don't get a execute of my example ```print``` statement. :(

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set the delegate in `cellForItemAt`:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: commentCell, for: indexPath) as! CommentCell
    cell.comment = comments[indexPath.item]
    cell.delegate = self. // You forgot to add this line

    return cell
}
```

you can read more about it here:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html

You can also search for great tutorials about it.

Comment: First of all I will thank you for your answer, but this was only a copy mistake which I have now corrected. The delegate is already set inside the ```cellForItemAt``` but it still not triggering the function.